# Why cant I save subsets with Not Enough Items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In NEI, I know you can save your own custom subset. But when I right click the subset area it won't show the saving loadouts. I have already tried right clicking. So can someone help please?

Comment: Left click? I think you want left click.

Comment: that edits the subset not allow to save i dont know why the saving part wont appear but it could be a mod im using heres all the ones i havein my mods folder (if it has  its in a folder) 
1.7.10CodeChickenLib-1.7.10-1.1.3.127-universal,
VoxelModsvoxelMap~~~,
WorldEditrhino,
WorldEdit,
Lucky block,
all-u-want,
applied energistics 2,
codechickencore,
extrautility,
holoinventory,
ichunutil,
liteloader,
lunatriuscore,
mocap,
mocap core,
voxelmap,
worldeditwrapper,
notenoughitem,
openblock,
openmodslib,
orespawn (main reason i need saving),
sync,
updatecheckermod,
waila,
examplemod (ingame)